# from django.template import Template

Tags: python, django, pydev

This code ( and more precisely the first line of this code )

```
from django.template import Template
from django.template import Context
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
t = Template('My name is {{ my_name }}.')
c = Context({'my_name': 'Foo Bar'})
t.render(c)
```

gives me this error stack:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 0.9.7\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272005\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1738, in <module>
  debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 0.9.7\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272005\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1355, in run
  pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 0.9.7\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272005\pysrc\_pydev_execfile.py", line 38, in execfile
  exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) #execute the script
File "C:\WORKSPACE\Liclipse\test\src\test.py", line 1, in <module>
  from django.template import Template
File "C:\win64app\Django\django\template\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
  from django.template.base import (ALLOWED_VARIABLE_CHARS, BLOCK_TAG_END,
File "C:\win64app\Django\django\template\base.py", line 268
  except TemplateSyntaxError, e:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I Have a PYTHONPATHvariable equal to this:

```
C:\win64app\Django\;C:\win64app\python33\Lib;C:\win64app\python33\DLLs
```

each and every folder exists. And django.template is clearly to be found there.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What version of Django is this? Only 1.6 or up is compatible with Python 3.

Comment: thanks this was it. I could not figure out the verion so I uninstall and reinstalled version 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old version of Django. Only versions 1.6 upwards are compatible with Python 3.